# AngularJS routing not loading ng-template on the initial click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a simple static website using AngularJS.
I am routing ng-view on my template to different html pages, like this one:

home.html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/home.html">
    You are in home
</script>
```

Here is my Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

        <title>My Website</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="author" content="Me">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="ContentController">
        <h1>My Website</h1>

        <ul class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
            <li><a href="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</li>
            <li><a href="portfolio"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Portfolio</li>
            <li><a href="articles"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Articles</li>
            <li><a href="books"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Books</li>
            <li><a href="about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>About Me</li>
        </ul>

        <ng-view></ng-view>

    </body>
</html>
```

My routing works just after the second time I click on each one of the links (portfolio, articles, ...).
The first time I click on a link, the controller is executed, but the view does not show me the html content (i.e. "You are in home" does not appear on my initial click, just after the second one).

If I write the content of home.html on the index.html file, then it works correctly also on my initial click.
However, I would like to understand why it is not loading correctly on the first time I click on each one of these links.

Could you guys help me?

Is there a proper way to use ng-template on a separate file? Or should I use a work around in order to reload my ng-template after the first click?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the ng-template, the issue is solved.
I will study more to understand how to use ng-template on separate files and will write it here.